# How to pass JVM arguments to Java Web Start from HTML

Tags: parameter-passing, java-web-start, java-deployment-toolkit

Using the [Deployment Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html), is it possible to launch a Java Web Start application through the function `deployJava.launchWebStartApplication`.
I would like to pass one additional dynamic information to the application, either as argument or as system property.

I saw that is is possible to define [JVM argument for applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html): using the parameter `java-vm-args` I could define system properties with `-D`. But i didn't find anything for javaws applications.

Of course, a solution can be implemented by using servlet that dinamically construct the jnlp file, but I definitely want to avoid this way.