# How to pass the Java 9 '--permit-illegal-access' flag to a Webstart application?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, java-9

I got my application running with JRE build 9-ea+163 by passing the `--permit-illegal-access` flag to the VM. Now I want to start the app with Java Webstart. A first try with

```
javaws -J--permit-illegal-access <JNLP-Url>
```

does not work. I get the same `InaccessibleObjectException` with `module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module` as without the flag.

Adding `<j2se java-vm-args="--permit-illegal-access" version="9*"/>` to the JNLP does not help.

Does Webstart support the `--permit-illegal-access` flag?

Can I furthermore specify the flag in the JNLP file?

Btw, with Java 9

```
javaws https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/samples/deployment/NotepadJWSProject/Notepad.jnlp
```

throws an `IllegalAccessException` and `-J--permit-illegal-access` doesn't help either.

P.S.: Setting the env variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to `--permit-illegal-access` works, but is not a solution since the clients are not accessible.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494787/enabling-jvm-options-with-java-web-start-jnlp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396426/passing-command-line-arguments-to-javaws-java-webstart-executable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932530/how-to-pass-unsafe-arguments-to-the-jvm-of-a-java-webstart-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958842/how-to-pass-jvm-arguments-to-java-web-start-from-html

Comment: Adding `<j2se java-vm-args="--permit-illegal-access" version="9*"/>` to the JNLP does not work.
Setting the env variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to `--permit-illegal-access` does work, but is not a solution since the clients are not accessible. The same holds for the deployment settings on the client computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java Web Start does not support the `--permit-illegal-access` option. JNLP apps that need to break encapsulation should use the precise options, there is support for both `--add-exports` and `--add-opens`.

Comment: Works for me with the proper syntax as described in [JDK-8172986] (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8172986) `java-vm-args="--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED"`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Add the following flag to vm argument:

```java
java --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED -jar mySpringBootApp.jar
```